# QGIS dxf2shp and the unit of text rotation angle

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

My problem is the following 
When Importing dxf with dxf2shp the rotation value for the text isent there

Here is part of my DXF file :

```
_______________
TEXT

  5

6881

330

6970

100

AcDbEntity

  8

Nummer

  6

Continuous

 62

     7

370

     0

100

AcDbText

 10

532781.146132

 20

6224946.688754

 30

0.0

 40

0.299994

  1

4036

 50

21.902297

  7

Style-font0

 72

     1

 11

532781.562917

 21

6224947.017986

 31

0.0

100

AcDbText

 73

     2

  0
__________________
```

The text angle (nr 50) is 21.902297

After importing in QGis there is an angle at 0.3822671964 - but I don't know where it is from.

Here is the same colum in QGis

```
  wkt_geom  tipx    tipy    tipz    tapx    tapy    tapz    height  scale   flags   hjust   vjust   text    style   angle
POINT(532781.14613200002349913     6224946.68875399976968765)       532781.146132       6224946.688754      0       532781.562917       6224947.017986      0       0.299994         1      0       1       2       4036        Style-font0     0.3822671964
```

Anybody who knows how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I can only answer where it is from - seems to be the angle converted from degrees into radians: `21.902297*Pi/180=0,38226719639`.

Comment: yes of course.
Then i can just do the reverse calculation.